# Display currently selected option in dropdown?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<form class="search-bar" data-example-id="search-bar">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented button dropdown">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div><!-- /.input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is get it functioning so that if a user clicks the dropdown and selections `Option 1`, `Option 1` will be displayed in the dropdown rather than the little caret glyph.

This is using Bootstrap, just to clarify.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for this , is this bootstrap? then you have to do it manually\

Answer (score 0):

You use Bootstrap Select instead of Bootstrap dropdown:

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some JS magic. Here's in jQuery flavour

**jQuery**

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.dropdown-toggle').text($(this).text());
  $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.dropdown-toggle').val($(this).text());
});
```

**Your `HTML`**

```
<form class="search-bar" data-example-id="search-bar">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented button dropdown">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div><!-- /.input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
</form>
```

And here's **[a working demo](http://www.bootply.com/3unSZTi4uN)**.

EDIT: You can stick this in the `head` of your page like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
                $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.dropdown-toggle').text($(this).text());
                $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.dropdown-toggle').val($(this).text());
            });

        });

 </script>
```

Comment: Hmm, this isn't working for some reason. I saved the JS and made sure it was added in (`<script src="dist/js/main.js"></script>`) but nothing happens when I click on an option in the dropdown. I've copied the code exactly as you have done.

Comment: @connormartin Have you made sure my piece of jquery is wrapped in a `$( document ).ready(function() {});` block?

Comment: @connormartin failing that, try, as a test, to isolate my code in the `head` of your page (see how in my updated answer).

Comment: @u r s u s I am using bootstrap, maybe that's why its not working?